# R shiny - combining ggplot2 and plotly to stack vertically 2 subplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-plotly

I would like to stack vertically 2 plots in a shiny app and use plotly to make them interactive.

I have the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel('Plot', plotOutput('plot')), 
    tabPanel('Plot2', plotly::plotlyOutput('plot2')), 
    tabPanel('Plot3', plotly::plotlyOutput('plot3'))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      p1 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) + 
        geom_line()
      p2 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + 
        geom_line()
      p1 / p2
    })
    
    output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
      p1 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) + 
        geom_line()
    })
    
    output$plot3 <- renderPlotly({
      p1 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) + 
        geom_line()
      p2 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) +
        geom_line()
      p1 / p2
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As you can see when only using **ggplot2** with the **patchwork** package ("Plot") it works as intended and stacks **p1** and **p2** vertically. Additionally, in "Plot2" when only plotting **p1** with ggplot2, it becomes interactive with plotly.

However, in "Plot3" when trying to convert the combined graph **(p1 / p2)** of "Plot" created with **patchwork** to interactive using plotly, it only plots the **p2** graph as interactive.

Any suggestions on how to create vertically stacked graphs using **ggplot2** and then make them interactive with **plotly** in a Shiny App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R plotly you can achive this via the `subplot` function:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel('Plot', plotOutput('plot')), 
    tabPanel('Plot2', plotly::plotlyOutput('plot2')), 
    tabPanel('Plot3', plotly::plotlyOutput('plot3'))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    p1 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) + 
      geom_line()
    p2 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + 
      geom_line()
    p1 / p2
  })
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
    p1 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) + 
      geom_line()
  })
  
  output$plot3 <- renderPlotly({
    p1 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) + 
      geom_line()
    p2 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) +
      geom_line()
    subplot(p1, p2, nrows = 2)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Please see [this](https://plotly.com/r/subplots/) for more information.